How to make a stack scrolling effect over a specific section of my webpage?
So I want to achieve the scrolling effect from this website:https://livingbeautyinc.com/
But the rub is I want it to happen only over a specific section of it, not the whole page.
So on the following page, for instance: https://codepen.io/Rafael-Sampaio-the-selector/pen/yLrpBRV
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Random BS</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                <h1 style="margin-top: 0;">
                    Poyo
                </h1>

                <p>Lorem ipsu... </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsu... </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsu... </p>
        </div>

        <div class="container-2">
                <p>Paya </p>

                <h2 style="margin-top: 0; position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
                    Service
                </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="container-3">
            <h1 style="margin-top: 0; color: wheat; position: relative; top: 300px; left: 500px;">
                Random text
            </h1>
        </div>
  
      <div class="container-4">
        <h1 style="margin-top: 0;">
          Yet more random text
        </h1>
      </div>
  
      <div class="container-5">
        <h1 style="margin-top: 0;">
          Once again random text
        </h1>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>`
`html, body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

div{
    height: 100%;
}

.container-2{
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.container-3{
    background-color: black;
}

.container-4{
  background-color: red;
}

.container-5{
  background-color: blue;
}`

I want the effect to be applied on container-2, container-3 and container-4, but the other two remain unaffected and scroll normally. How would I go around doing that?
I tried doing what the answer on this question suggested: Scrolling effect - Make components stack on top of each other when scrolling CSS
But that only works when you're applying the effect on the entire page, doing on an specific section only managed to break the layout, little else.

You can use position sticky for that effect :


//this code generate the HTML (10 container)
let HTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  HTML += `
<div class="container">
  <h1> Poyo N°` + i + `</h1>

  <p>Lorem ipsu... </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsu... </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsu... </p>
</div>
`;
}
document.querySelector(".sticky").innerHTML = HTML;
.container {
  /* We use 100 Dynamic Viewport Units to take the full screen height  
Learn more about that here https://dev.to/frehner/css-vh-dvh-lvh-svh-and-vw-units-27k4
*/
  min-height: 100dvh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


/* 
THE CSS BELOW IS FOR THIS CODE SNIPPET ONLY 
*/

body,
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  background-color: gray;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  min-height: 100dvh;
}

.container:nth-child(1n) {
  background-color: green;
}

.container:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: blue;
}
<section>
  <h1>Regular section 1 </h1>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>Regular section 2 </h1>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="sticky">
    <!-- We add inside sticky the HTML, in this exemple i am using Javascript to make it easier to read -->
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>Regular section 3</h1>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>Regular section 4</h1>
</section>




Does it only work if the HTML is added through JavaScript?

No, i added the HTML using JavaScript to make the HTML tab in this exemple shorter and easier to read
